# What does this word 'ringer' mean here?

Tags: meaning

> I'm never quite sure if I took a great photo, until I get home and pull it up full screen... and even then, I still have to see how it turns out after processing....
>
> But after all that, when I produce a ringer, its the same feeling as catching a big fish  lol
>
> Somewhat euphoric, two hands in the air, and Ta Da !   lol
> <sub>—Fishchris on [Digital Photography Review Forums](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/60765586)</sub>

I thought it is like, 'a contestant you bid to a competition (such as an animal (a horse, a bull..etc.) or a robot, an athlete,' or as in here, 'a photo you submit for a competition'.
But, this ↓ definition says it means something like 'an athlete you *illegally* bid for a competition'... kinda?

> An athlete or horse fraudulently substituted for another in a competition or event.
> <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ringer)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

From context, it's pretty clear that it refers to a really good picture.

I haven't been able to find the corresponding definition in any free dictionary (because it's "rare", I guess), so here's the definition from the OED:

> *Austral. slang.* Something superlatively good. Now *rare*.

Answer (score 0):

All I can come up with is related to the usage of "dead ringer" often used for someone that looks very much like someone else.

As the context is photography I can see the connection, but it could wellbe that he's taken a bit of slang and made it his own.